# Scheduling MVC 4 - C# to call a function at specific time

Tags: c#, sms, asp.net-mvc-4, scheduling

I'm new in *`MVC 4`* and this is my first project of this technology, I went through the [Movie](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/intro-to-aspnet-mvc-3) and [ContosoUniversity](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) examples from [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials).

The site claims to sell prepaid products.
The db contains tables of User, Dealer, Supplier...etc.

I'm trying to schedule my system.

For example every evening at 23:59,  a particular function will be called and retrieved from the database all the usernames and passwords that meet a specific query.

I also need to send SMS by a certain date, I assigned a separate column on the table which will keep the alert issued towards the end of the service.

I'd love to hear about ideas and how to start messing with system scheduling or realization of the specific idea.

Thanks and pardon me for my English.

Comment: Passwords should be one-way hashed.. there should be no way for you to be able to tell if a password meets specific criteria.  If you aren't doing it that way, you're a serious security hazard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

finally I did it within the global asax. I don't know if it the best way but it work..

Here is the code.

```
protected void Application_Start()
    {
        try
        {

           .
           .
           .
            SetTimer();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ...
        }
    }


    private static void SetTimer()
    {
        DateTime tomorow = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);
        DateTime midnight = new DateTime(tomorow.Year, tomorow.Month, tomorow.Day, 0, 0, 0);
        TimeSpan d = midnight - DateTime.Now;

        sTimer.Enabled = true;
        sTimer.Interval = d.TotalMilliseconds;
        sTimer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(sTimer_Elapsed);
        sTimer.Start();
    }

    static void sTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        sTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromHours(24).TotalMilliseconds;
        db = new CompanyContext();

        //some func
        sendInOutUsers();            
        AlartUsers();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do the scheduling as a separate component outside your MVC project. Typically you would create a Windows Service project that runs all the time on the IIS server (or other server) which would include a Timer to launch different tasks at specified schedules. You could create a configuration file, or a table in your database containing the schedules and other execution information and query this file or table from the service.

Comment: You can test before deployment by installing the service somewhere else, possibly your own development workstation. Ideally you need to have a test environment that is setup to simulate production.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a separate windows service on the server that will run at scheduled times? I have personally implemented this, and it worked well.

Comment: And calling my function from the web service?

Comment: You could share an assembly containing the functions you want to run at an interval and functions you want to run on demand. This would allow your windows server to perform its functions at midnight, and your website to perform its functions immediately.